# Powershell. count the number of duplicate entries in a file

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with a list of IP addresses, and i need to count the number of times the same IP appears in the file.

I've found lots of ways of removing duplicate entries, and how to count the number of lines, but nothing on how to counting duplicate entries.

I haven't got much of a script yet, not anything worth posting, but if someone can point me in the right direction, that will be a start.

Comment: You really haven't given us much info. What does the file look like, just a list of IP's, one per line? If so you want Group-Object. Run with that, and come back when you have a script that we can see and help with if you have issues.

Comment: That was just the start i needed thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If `$file` contains

```
10.1.1.2  
10.1.1.2  
10.1.1.2  
10.1.1.10  
10.1.1.10  
10.1.1.20
```

then

```
Get-Content $file | Group-Object -noelement

Count Name                     
----- ----                     
3     10.1.1.2                 
2     10.1.1.10                
1     10.1.1.20
```

Comment: Most of my logs have timestamps, is there a way i can ignore the first part (timestamp) of each line?